# Altitude from Google Play Services Fused Location Provider

Tags: android, gps, google-play-services

I am successfully receiving latitude and longitude information with high accuracy from my device's GPS. To achieve this I followed the tutorial here: https://developer.android.com/training/location/index.html

However, I also would like a value for altitude from the GPS. Is this not possible? The Location object I receive always returns zero:

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    Log.i(TAG, location.getAltitude()); // returns 0.0!
}
```

I'm using `LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY`, so I'm assuming the Fused Location Provider is using the GPS and not WiFi or some other means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From this [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#Location(java.lang.String)), By default, Location's latitude and longtitude are 0 and the location has no bearing, altitude, speed, accuracy or extras.

So you can only get the altitude if it is available. Not all location have an altitude.

You can use the `hasAltitude()` method that return a boolean results to know if the location has an altitude.

Comment: This is essentially the most information I could find too. Might have to look into other providers for this data.